# Hide all traces of a program that is running

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

So this question is kind of interesting, I think. And before I lose anyones attention or they start shoving their fingers into my face with accusations: no I am not making or attempting to make a virus. I actually had a really good idea for a game. This game will be kind of like a creepy pasta(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creepypasta), in that it will mimic the ideals of a "haunted game". This game, when launched, will play for only a few seconds before ultimately "crashing" back to the desktop. It is at this time that I would like to hide all traces of its existence(which is still running in the background) so that I may continue with phase 2 of the game. During this phase, I will randomly take control of a console window, or play creepy sound effects at arbitrary/random intervals. The game will open back up at random, as if it has a mind of its own, too, but the game will be different each time this happens.

I would like to hide the game from the task manager completely. So this window:[image]

Will show absolutely nothing of the program, no matter the tab the user selects. I want the game to, quite literally, turn into a ghost. The programming language that I am planning on using is C# and for the graphics library, OpenTK(Which is irrelevant for this question, but I want to make sure I lay down as much information as possible).

Anyone have any ideas? Oh, and I should also mention that I am quite fluent in the .NET framework/api, and I can build any windows forms application by hand(without using the editor).

**Update:**

I just thought of a fun alternative to hiding it. The answer: make the program smarter. Send the program to desktop, then listen for the opening of a task manager. If it opens, my program immediately shuts down task manager and the game responds with something super creepy like "But i thought you wanted to play with me? Why are you trying to kill me?" in a console. Sounds awesome. Lol.

Comment: I really, really hope that there is absolutely no way that Microsoft has built something like this into the .NET language.  You may not think you are building a virus, but the only difference between what you are describing and a virus is semantics.

Comment: Windows doesn't let programs hide themselves like that, for obvious reasons. If you could do this, every virus would do this. You would have write a root-kit to get this working.

Comment: @Blorgbeard pretty sure I have seen programs do this, and by that I mean specifically "viruses"/Malware.

Comment: @Krythic Indeed, but they have to use a root kit.  As I recall, Sony did something similar as a DRM measure and got hit with a hefty class action lawsuit, and that was in the 90's/00's, nowadays you would probably get arrested for domestic terrorism.

Comment: @Namfuak Blizzard does this, too, with World of Warcraft. They have a separate executable that runs along side the program (Invisible except in the processes tab) which detects if the player is using any other programs that may be contrived as bots.

Comment: "Domestic terrorism" is extreme hyperbole. The most that would likely happen is... your "game" gets classified as a virus. The Blizzard executable is nothing special; it just never opens a window. There is no way to legitimately hide a program from all of Task Manager. Some people have tried to "coerce" Task Manager into hiding their programs; as you imagine, this can get ugly (and thanks to UIPI might not even be possible anymore). Also [your game concept sounds very familiar](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/Imscared).

Comment: @Krythic Most likely because you did not *show* any research. Writing viruses is almost as old as CS itself, so plenty of possible ways of hiding programs/code for all sorts of OS is already described everywhere. You also did not propose any concrete way of implementing your feature and instead add whole lot of unrelated text to the post.

Comment: This would be malware. Irrespective of you intentions. It also would not be a game. Well, you the malware author might have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert but I think most techniques that deals with process hiding uses `CreateRemoteThread`.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437(v=vs.85).aspx

It is pretty tough to get right, but there are maaany blogs about it, eg:
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/using-createremotethread-for-dll-injection-on-windows/

This works by picking some victim process that is already running, like say svchost.exe and add your thread into this.

Also while speaking of svchost, you can also very legally register a service and be hosted by this windows process, your clients may see the running game by calling the listing command:

```
 tasklist /svc /fi "imagename eq svchost.exe"
```

or:
http://www.howtogeek.com/80082/svchost-viewer-shows-exactly-what-each-svchost-exe-instance-is-doing/

This is a tad more hidden than directly appearing as a task, while remainging more gentle to the user than the CreateRemoteThread. Also less crash prone, and also, anti viruses usually hook CreateRemoteThread to block calls to it.